# Flutter analysis_options.yaml is missing

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My Flutter project does not have `analysis_options.yaml` file as the package [effective_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/effective_dart/example) is asking me to use in order to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the project does not come by default with the file `analysis_options.yaml`.

So Just adding it manually in the base of the project (same folder as the `pubspec.yaml`) will work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/81417 fixed https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78432 with a lot `analysis_options.yaml` into templates

Answer (score 0):

flutter pub add --dev flutter_lints